# Curvature of a spacecurve that is a derivative of another space curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, curvature

Let $\vec{r}(t)$ be a spacecurve such that  $|{\vec{r'}(t)}|=1$ everywhere.
Consider a new spacecurve such that $\vec{u}(t)=\vec{r'}(t)$.

Prove that the curvature of the new curve equals $\sqrt{1+\frac{\tau^2}{\kappa^2}}$ , where $\tau$ and $\kappa$ are the torsion and curvature of the original curve.

the equation for torsion is $\tau=\frac{[ r' r'' r''']}{|r'X r''|^2}$
and that of curvature of original curve is $\kappa=\frac{[ r' X r''|}{r'^3}$

Comment: Hint: How is the torsion defined?
If this doesn't help, write here the definition and I'll help you from there on

Comment: Is $t$ arc length? parameter? Constant tangent vector length? Are you referring to helices/involutes? Do you mean new curve has curvature $ \sqrt{\tau^2 + \kappa^2}? $

Comment: @OfekGillon I have added the equations for torsion and curvature

Comment: @Narasimham the curve is parametrized by arc length (which is the reason why magnitude of the first derivative is 1)

Comment: @Narasimham t is just a parameter, no the curvature should be $\sqrt{1+\frac{\tau^2}{\kappa^2}}$

Comment: Is the large X in the added formulas the vector cross product?

Comment: @coffeemath yeah it is

Comment: Problem from a standard text-book? How can the new curvature lose ts dimension?

Comment: @Narasimham no not from a textbook as far as I know, It was in an honors assignment.

Comment: @Narasimham I am not sure I understand what you mean by curvature losing its dimension

Comment: In physics curvature or torsion has dimension 1/L. Your new curvature is dimensionless. Something disagrees.

Comment: See [**another answer**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036111/given-a-helix-consider-the-curve-of-its-tangent-express-the-curvature-and-tor/2036332#2036332)